# "mi_mail" is not defined python

Tags: python-3.x

me aparce el error mi_email is not define cunado en realidad ya lo tengo definido como se muestra en el video, adjunto imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
texto en negrita

por motivos de privacidad e recortado el seccion donde aparece el email

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Te invito a leer [ask] y realizar el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo elaborar buenas preguntas. En tu caso has pegado código en forma de imagen, y eso no ayuda a recibir buenas respuesta, y puede ser catalogada como una pregunta de baja calidad y ser cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Debes poner un [example] de tu caso para que sea mejor atendida por la comunidad, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No haz inicializado la variable `mi_mail`.

La variable `mi_mail` que usas dentro de una función no existe fuera de ella.

Tu código sólo alcanza a ejecutar una instrución

```
bp = Blueprint(algunos parametros)
```

antes de fallar en la siguiente línea

```
mail = Email(mi_mail, mas cosas que me da lata copiar)
```

pues no haz inicializado `mi_mail`.

**Solución**

Inicializa `mi_mail` como primera cosa en tu código.

Te mostraría el código correcto, pero como sólo has publicado una foto, andas de mala suerte.